# Receiving fcm in iOS when app is foreground (flutter)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not able to show message in iOS when app is open. Android working fine. I am receiving message but is in a form something like = ['aps']['alert'], can I somehow convert it so I would be able to use local notification package to show it, like I am showing in android back and foreground.

This is how I'm showing the notification (in onMessage):

_notifications.showNotification(message['notification']['body']);

This is how fcm is configured:

```
_fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
});
_fcm.getToken().then((value) {
});
```

Problem occurs when I'm sending test messages from firebase console. Also if I send them like this:

````
public static function sendNotificationToRegisteredUsers($message){
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => $message,
    'title'     => 'Test',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1,
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);*/
);
$fields = array
(
    'to' => '/topics/TestTopic',
    'notification' => $msg,
    'priority' => 'high',
    'android' => [
        //'collapseKey' => 'daily_event',
        'priority' => 'high',
        /*'notification' => [
            'sound' => 'default'
        ]*/
        ],
    'apns' => [
        'headers' => [
            'apns-priority' => '10'
        ],
        'payload' => [
            'aps' => [
                'alert' => [
                    'title' => 'Test',
                    'body' => $message,
                ],
                'badge' => 42,
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
 
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
}```


Thank you
````

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following lines to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.swift file of your iOS project

Objective-C:

if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>) self;
}
Swift:

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```